# Is it possible to extract a .cls from a .dtx and avoid the Two \LoadClass commands error?

Tags: dtx

I have tried to adapt [Joseph Wright's model dtx file](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/) for a class that I'm writing based on the `article` class (a reduced working example is below, which I have named `democlass.dtx`).  But when I run `pdflatex democlass.dtx` I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Two \LoadClass commands.`  Clearly, there is only one `\LoadClass` statement, so it must be getting loaded a second time somewhere.

So, is it possible to extract a .cls file from a .dtx file when the .cls file is based on the `article` class?  I've searched high and low for a solution, and I'm stumped.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
demopkg --- readme text and license (truncated for this example)
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
demopkg --- readme text and license (truncated for this example)

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright, maintenance, and included files (truncated for this example)

\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.cls}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{class}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*class>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{demopkg}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
%</class>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% 
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.cls}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{demopkg} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}. 
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%    
%\begin{macro}{\LoadClass}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\LoadClass{article}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro} 
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your example.  You are trying to generate a class file, but you are trying include it with `\usepackage{jobname}`, which will not work, and complain that `democlass.sty` is not found.

Comment: After disabling the `\usepackage{\jobname}` which should only be included for packages, not classes, your example compiles fine for me. I don't get any error. However, I guess the cause of trouble is the `\ProvidesClass` line before the `\documentclass`. It should be there, at least not in this form, because it is taken as part of the driver document. There are some `\iffalse` .. `\fi` missing or use `%<class>\ProvidesClass` instead. In Joseph's original it is the same for a package but this might not cause this much trouble.

Comment: Thank you -- this helps a great deal.  I had typed in `democlass.cls` at the prompt for `democlass.sty`; I'm guessing that is what caused the second `\LoadClass`.  However, now that I have deleted `\usepackage{\jobname}` from the dtx, my pdf documentation displays `?` for the `\fileversion` and `\filedate`.  I suspect this has to do with `\GetFileInfo{\jobname.cls}`.  Is there some other value that I can use for `\GetFileInfo` so that the file version and date are displayed correctly in my documentation?

Comment: Never mind -- I figured out that I can use a `\def` at the top of my .dtx file and fill in the values that way.  Martin, can you submit your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @lockstep: Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After disabling the `\usepackage{\jobname}` which should only be included for packages, not classes, your example compiles fine for me. I don't get any error. However, I guess the cause of trouble is the `\ProvidesClass` line before the `\documentclass`. It should be there, at least not in this form, because it is taken as part of the driver document. There are some `\iffalse` .. `\fi` missing or use `%<class>\ProvidesClass` instead. In Joseph's original it is the same for a package but this might not cause this much trouble.