# Using .cls macros in the typesetting of the .dtx from which .cls is generated

Tags: dtx

I read some advice suggesting that when writing a package, one should use that
package in one's `dtx` file in order to demonstrate the use of macros and
environments. Presumably, the same should be true when writing a class, but I'm
encountering the issue of not knowing how to actually do this. Attempting to
stick `\LoadClass{\jobname}` (or even `\LoadClass{democls}` assuming the file
is named `democls.dtx`) leads to a two `\LoadClass` commands error. (Note: I
don't think my question is a duplicate of
[Is it possible to extract a .cls from a .dtx and avoid the Two \LoadClass commands error?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30506/is-it-possible-to-extract-a-cls-from-a-dtx-and-avoid-the-two-loadclass-comman)
because it doesn't seem like that question addresses directly using macros and
environments defined by the class in the typesetting of the class
documentation. I am basing my democls on the same Joseph Wright model `dtx`
file, though.)

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
(preamble)
\endpreamble
\postamble
(postamble)
\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.cls}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{class}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*class>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{democls}[2015/07/07 v1.0 description text]
%</class>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% 
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.cls}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{democls} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{email: you+obfuscation@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%%
%\maketitle
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}. It looks like \examplemacro{foo}{bar}.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\LoadClass{article}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\examplemacro}[2][]{%
  \textit{#1 #2}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro} 
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

edit: If anyone cares to make use of the finished templates, they're available at https://github.com/RyanMatlock/LaTeX-dtx-templates.

Comment: Whilst using the source `.dtx` as a demo is common for packages (which are normally safe to mix in with other code), for classes that is far less likely to be the case. Specialised classes may well be poorly suited to actually typesetting the documentation (which will have lots of code-related material in it). I would favour using a separate `.tex` file as a demo.

Comment: When you say "a separate `.tex` file," I don't see any reason not to include it in between `%<*demo>`...`%</demo>` guards and create it with `\generate{\file{demodoc.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{demo}}`. You could maybe get really fancy and have your first pass of `pdflatex democls.dtx` also generate a bash script that runs `makeindex` on `democls.tex`, `pdflatex` on `democls.dtx` and `demodoc.tex`, and then `mv`s the `.cls` file to `$TEXMFHOME`. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, of course one can included such a demo file in the `.dtx`. (Generating a script doesn't work so well cross-platform, so I'd tend to avoid.) My experience is that for a small package an 'all in one' `.dtx` works but as projects get bigger this becomes more tricky: editing big files, _etc._ is not so easy. For example, I've recently split up `achemso` to have a separate demo file rather than bundle it in the `.dtx`. Your call, of course.